# Updating fiield in PostgreSQL table using .update() not working in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I've been trying to update the `invo_payment_method` value from a table called `Invoices`. This is the code that I currently have to try to achieve this:

```
if total_payments_for_invoice.all().count() == 1:
    invoice_object = Invoice.objects.get(slug=slug)
    invoice_object.invo_payment_method = request.POST.get('payment_method')
    invoice_object.save()
```

So what I'm trying to do is if it's the first payment for the invoice I want to get `invoice_object` which has the slug of the invoice that just got a payment and update the `invo_payment_method` field in the table and save the changes. But that's not working. I also tried doing the following:

```
if total_payments_for_invoice.all().count() == 1:
    Invoice.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(
        invo_payment_method=request.POST.get('payment_method'))
```

And it's not working either. After that I tried adding a the following to the code above:

```
if total_payments_for_invoice.all().count() == 1:
    Invoice.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(
        invo_payment_method=request.POST.get('payment_method')).save()
```

And this one actually updated the value in the database, but it made the webpage crash because of the following exception: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save'`. In case more information is needed, if I print the value of `Invoice.objects.get(slug=slug)` I get the following: *INV-bb1c 21*. And if I print the value of `Invoice.objects.filter(slug=slug)` I get the following: `<QuerySet [<Invoice: INV-bb1c 21>]>`. In both cases I'm getting the invoice number which is *INV-bb1c* and the invoice pid which is *21*. Please see image attached of how the `Invoice` table looks like. Any help would be greatly appreciated. To clarify: `invo_payment_method` is initially `null` in the database and `request.POST.get('payment_method')` returns a string of the payment method used.

[image]

Comment: What does `request.POST.get('payment_method')` return? Is it different from the stored `invo_payment_method`?

Comment: Yes, the ```invo_payment_method``` is ```null``` until a payment method is added, which is right there, and ```request.POST.get('payment_method')``` returns a string of the payment method. For example: if the payment method is Debit Card, it would return Debit Card. @BrianDestura